# What is the best way to implement Loading indicator in redux-saga app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I'm developing app with (redux + redux-saga + typescript + typesafe-actions + ducks)

I'm considering how to implement loading indicator during api call.

this is my structure

```
  state
    ducks
      common
        actions.ts
        reducers.ts
        sagas.ts
        selectors.ts
      group
        same as common/
      user
        same as common/
```

common/actions

```
export const beginLoading = () => action(CommonActionTypes.BEGIN_LOADING);
export const endLoading = () => action(CommonActionTypes.END_LOADING);
```

group/sagas

```
export function* handleFetchGroup() {
  try {
    const { group } = yield call(
      Api.fetchGroup
    );
    yield put(addGroup(group));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

user/sagas

```
export function* handleFetchUsers(action: addGroup) {
  try {
    yield take(ADD_GROUP);
    const users = yield call(
      Api.fetchUsers,
      action.payload.id
    );
    yield put(addUsers(users));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

At first, I tried this.

group/sagas

```
export function* handleFetchGroup() {
  try {
    yield put(beginLoading()); // added
    const { group } = yield call(
      Api.fetchGroup
    );
    for(const group of groups) {
        yield put(addGroup(group));
    }
    yield put(endLoading()); // added
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(endLoading());
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

in this case, the loading indicator shows only during fetching group data.

so I tried this.

```
export function* handleFetchGroup() {
  try {
    yield put(beginLoading()); 
    const { groups } = yield call(
      Api.fetchGroups
    );
    for(const group of groups) {
        yield put(addGroup(group));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(endLoading());
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

user/sagas

```
export function* handleFetchUsers(action: addGroup) {
  try {
    yield take(ADD_GROUP);
    const users = yield call(
      Api.fetchUsers,
      action.payload.id
    );
    yield put(addUsers(users));
    yield put(endLoading()); // added
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    yield put(endLoading());
  }
}
```

in this case,the loading indicator disappeared when the first fetchUsers finished.

Finally I tried this.

```
export function* handleFetchGroup() {
  try {
    yield put(beginLoading());
    const { groups } = yield call(
      Api.fetchGroups
    );
    for(const group of groups) { 
        const users = yield call(Api.fetchUsers, group.id); // add
        yield put(addUsers(users));
    }
    yield put(endLoading());
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(endLoading());
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

But in this case, group saga depends on user entity.
So I want to avoid this, but I didn't come up with it.

Do you have any solution??

Comment: I dont't fully understand your issue. Do you have multiple API calls and you want to show a loading while all of them load? Or is it only 1 call (the `Api.fetchGroups`) ? In general you should show the user as many information as possible as soon as you can. So holding back on all API calls could potentially take a long time. So you could think about adding a loading per API call and then only show a loading indicator on certain "areas" on the website. I'd also attach those loading states to the actions you already have. E.g. `ADD_GROUP` (start loading) and `addUsers(users)` (stop loading)

Comment: Thank you for responding.In my case,"show a loading while all of them load" is better. I can't get "attach those loading states to the actions". Can you give me a sample code??

Comment: Consider using a `finally` block that does `yield put(endLoading())`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to have `isLoading` property in user state and group state. When action `beginLoading` for group is emitted (I assume, that this action will trigger `handleFetchGroup`), set `isLoading: true` in group reducer. When group loading is finished, set `isLoading: false` in group reducer.

Exactly the same logic implement for user. So `isLoading` which exist in user reducer will be set in response to `beginLoading` for user and so on.

In component, which will display loading indicator have `isLoading` from group and `isLoading` from user and show loading indicator whenever either of two is true.

For example (not tested, use as  hint)

```
const LoadingIndicator: FC<{ user: UserState, group: GroupState }> = ({group, user}) => (
    group.isLoading || user.isLoading ? <div>Loading...</div> : null
}

export default connect(state => ({ user: state.user, group: state.group }), {})(LoadingIndicator)
```

I also see that you're triggering `handleFetchUsers` in response to `ADD_GROUP`. This also better to decouple. You may consider creating additional saga (for example `loadAll`) which will trigger user load in response to group load finish.

For example (not tested)

```
function *loadAll() {
    yield put(BEGIN_GROUP_LOAD)
    yield takeEvery(GROUP_LOAD_FINISHED, function*(action) => {
        yield handleFetchUsers(action)
    }
}
```